# Ubuntu 18.04 update hibernate hangs

Tags: hibernate, ubuntu

After updating ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 I can't get hibernate to work.

I tried everything:

> sudo -s
>
> echo platform > /sys/power/disk
>
> echo disk > /sys/power/state

and

> sudo -s
>
> echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
>
> echo disk > /sys/power/state

and

> sudo apt-get install uswsusp
>
> sudo s2disk

and

installed hibernate 2.0+15+g88d54a8-1.deb

> sudo hibernate

In every case the computer hangs on a blank screen and never shuts down.
On the other hand, suspend is working. But I need to save to disk so I can unplug the pc.

does anyone have this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 5):

Here are all the "possible" steps for Ubuntu 18.04, make sure all of them passes. It's a little tricky since you are upgrading.

**1- Make sure hibernate is installed**

```
sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate pm-hibernate
```

Then try:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

(for you this step doesn't work)

**2- Make sure you have enough swap AND you are pointing to the correct one**

Run this to check your swap:

```
grep swap /etc/fstab
```

You should get something like:

```
swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=xyz-bb32-4ad2-aaeb-xyz none     swap    sw
```

If not, then you need to create one (I guess this will work for you).

**3- Copy the UUID of the swap into grub**

Copy the UUID from the previous step into the grup file (I'm pretty sure it's your problem.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then change the resume to piont to the UUID not the dev name:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=xyz-bb32-4ad2-aaeb-xyz"
```

**4- Enable Hibernate (if not already)**

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Then past in that file:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

**5- Hibernate when lid is closed**

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

And include

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend 
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
```

Comment: At the end I reinstalled a fresh version of Ubuntu 18.04, which I read does not need a swap partition. Instead I have a swap file of 20Gb (16GB RAM), but still can't get it to work. I am getting the same problem; when I hibernate I get a blank screen and the computer never shuts down.

Comment: Does this happen when you run `sudo pm-hibernate` in the shell?

Comment: Is sleep working? (it's known to have issues with 18.04).
Also, what is your laptop?

Comment: yes I run sudo pm-hibernate and I get a black screen with a message on top "s2disk ...." and it freezes, Never switches of the pc. Yes sleep mode is working perfectly, but I need to power of the computer. Its a desktop pc (I7, 16GB RAM) not a laptop.

Comment: What's the output of `grep swap /etc/fstab` ?

Comment: /swapfile    none    swap    sw    0    0

Comment: A small typos in `HandleLidSwitch`: **L**id instead of **l**id.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have removed that anyway. I made a mistake, because I don't have a laptop but a desktop pc.

Comment: Double check the swap configuration: `ls -lh /swapfile`. This should show 20GB, something like `rw------- 1 root root 20.0G Oct 25 11:14 /swapfile`

Comment: yes first one is: -rw------- 1 root root 20G set  2 10:14 /swapfile

Comment: second: /swapfile file  20G   0B   -2

Comment: after updating grub configuration please execute: `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 1):

I searched high an low for a solution to this problem. My Dell E7450 simply failed to hibernate regardless of the many different methods I tried.  Lots of the different articles reference an entry in fstab consisting on a UUID but my fstab  swapfile entry was mounted here /swapfile so many of the articles weren't applicable.

One day I stumbled upon this article which actually works!  Its a long series of steps so pay attention, it is the only method that actually works so follow these steps and you'll be hibernating to your hearts delight! (I can't take any credit for this one!):

https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/14/configuring-lubuntu-18-04-to-enable-hibernation-using-a-swap-file/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a swap file, I suggest starting over by following this tutorial which will make sure it is properly configured:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks, I had already seen this guide and already have a active swapfile.

Answer (score 0):

You are using uswsusp - which has this open bug about freezing during hibernate, particularly when there is too much data to write to swap, as to Buffered IO gets suspended as part of Hibernate:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1819915

The bug appears to still be open, but a guy at the bottom of the thread posted a workaround which does work for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

> I was able to work around this by writing a Hibernate script and
> assigning a keyboard shortcut to it:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Unlimiting IO cache...
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=100
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=100

sleep 5
sudo s2disk

echo Re-limiting IO cache...
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=10
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=20
```

> This disables cached disk IO for the hibernate and restores it after resume.

I've had no hibernate issues for nearly a year with this approach.  One drawback is the script won't trigger if your battery gets critically low (though there might be a way to do this).